# DKIM - partial signing (`l` parameter); reduce computational overhead

Tags: email, dkim

Does anyone have any experience signing only a part of a message body with DKIM?

The DKIM specification allows one to limit the amount of message body used in computing a signature; a parameter in the email's DKIM-Header ('l') can be used to indicate to recipient servers how much of the body is actually signed.  I can reduce the amount of CPU consumed by my MTAs if I can limit this, but it's obviously not worth the trouble if it causes deliverability problems.

In practice, are mail providers requiring the entire body be signed?

References:

```
rfc4871 - DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)
...
   A body length specified in the "l=" tag of the signature limits the
   number of bytes of the body passed to the verification algorithm.
   All data beyond that limit is not validated by DKIM.  Hence,
   verifiers might treat a message that contains bytes beyond the
   indicated body length with suspicion, such as by truncating the
   message at the indicated body length, declaring the signature invalid
   (e.g., by returning PERMFAIL (unsigned content)), or conveying the
   partial verification to the policy module.
```

.

```
opendkim.8

-L min[%+] - Instructs the verification code to fail messages for 
             which a partial signature was received.
```

Thanks for your input!